# Exact meaning of "Too good a/of a X" clause and etymology

Tags: clauses

As a non-native speaker, couldn't find a way to find this clause on the web, and need either links or explanation.

I often see this:

> This is too rigid a procedure.
>
> He is too good an ordinary worker.

Is this equal to *"of a"* clause (*too rigid of a procedure*)?

What are other ways of using, besides "too X a/of a Y"?

When did these constructs appear? This seems to appear quite often, but in the 14 years I was learning English at School and University, it hasn't been mentioned ever.

Comment: Chaucer uses it:  "Ye han wonne hym with *to gret an ese*."

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/njwxmzf

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/qxxqt4c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UK English I usually hear "too good a."

In US English you will find both "too good a" and  "too good of a."  There is still a preponderance of the former.

The expressions are equivalent.

As for the history of the phrase, look [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+good+a%2Ctoo+good+an%2Ctoo+good+of+a%2Ctoo+good+of+an&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20good%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20good%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20good%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20good%20of%20an%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Comment: wow, interesting. I wonder if this graph means it dying off?

Comment: "too good", surely?

Comment: @DocOccupant  -  Oops, thanks. I managed to type it into ngram okay but not in the answer! Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, they're not equivalent in register; "too good a" is more formal and appropriate for writing, while "too good of a" is informal and less appropriate for writing.  It's conversational.

I found a comment on the inappropriateness of "too good of a" in an advice column, [This Is Not Too Good 'of a' Usage](http://www.creators.com/lifestylefeatures/words-and-trivia/rob-kyff-word-guy/this-is-not-too-good-of-a-usage.html), and evidently the Oxford Book of American Usage and Style says the same, but unfortunately the e-book I found started with the letter "p" and the explanation is under the entry for "of."