# Too big of a something meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

The recruiter asked me this:

> This might be a too big of a company you’re looking for!

I don’t get what does this mean?

Comment: What part aren’t you sure of? You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 'too big of an issue' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/499211/is-too-big-of-an-issue-correct) OR [Exact meaning of "Too good a/of a X" clause and etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263482/exact-meaning-of-too-good-a-of-a-x-clause-and-etymology)

Answer (score 0):

This is an insult, hurled at you in a diplomatic(?) manner. I have posted a few links which makes this clear.

Answer by Say Keng Lee in https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-they-say-he-she-is-too-good-for-you?share=1

"Too good to be true" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/too%20good%20to%20be%20true

Too clever​/​nice​/​generous etc for your own good https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/too-clever-nice-generous-etc-for-your-own-good

> so clever​/​nice​/​generous etc that it is a disadvantage instead of
> an advantage

Sorry I could not find more authoritative source. But in colloquial and idiomatic use when someone says "too good", it is not a compliment.